# Countdown timer goes awry after the second click on "Start"

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I was trying to build a very simple game where you have to click the buttons that pop (1 is pop and 0 is not pop) as fast as you can in one minute (to get the highest number of whacks possible in that timeframe). I am able to start my app and start the counter by clicking on the "start" button,

but if for some reason I mistakenly click "start" again after a few seconds, the counter goes awry and it alternates quickly between the first countdown and the second countdown. What is wrong with my code? Also, I do not know how to make the whacks counter go to 0 when the countdowntimer gets to 0 (or "Done!") automatically. Can you help?

Thank you very much for your time!

This is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.whack_a_lock_022;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int cl = 0;
    int nl = 0;
    int sl = 0;
    int whacks = 0;
    int maxwhacks = 0;
    float random0to1;
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    private Button start;
    private Button cancel;
    private TextView time;
    Random r;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        r = new Random();

        Button clButton = findViewById(R.id.cl);
        Button nlButton = findViewById(R.id.nl);
        Button slButton = findViewById(R.id.sl);

        View.OnClickListener btnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch(v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.startButton :
                        start();
                        break;
                    case R.id.cancelButton :
                        cancel();
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        clButton.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (cl == 1) {
                    cl = 0;
                    TextView CapsLock = findViewById(R.id.cl);
                    CapsLock.setText("0");
                    whacks++;
                    TextView NumberOfWhacks = findViewById(R.id.numberOfWhacksView);
                    NumberOfWhacks.setText(String.valueOf(whacks));
                    if (whacks > maxwhacks) {
                        maxwhacks = whacks;
                        TextView NumberOfMaxWhacks = findViewById(R.id.numberOfMaxWhacksView);
                        NumberOfMaxWhacks.setText(String.valueOf(maxwhacks));
                    }

                    pop();
                }
            }
        });

        nlButton.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (nl == 1) {
                    nl = 0;
                    TextView NumLock = findViewById(R.id.nl);
                    NumLock.setText("0");
                    whacks++;
                    TextView NumberOfWhacks = findViewById(R.id.numberOfWhacksView);
                    NumberOfWhacks.setText(String.valueOf(whacks));
                    if (whacks > maxwhacks) {
                        maxwhacks = whacks;
                        TextView NumberOfMaxWhacks = findViewById(R.id.numberOfMaxWhacksView);
                        NumberOfMaxWhacks.setText(String.valueOf(maxwhacks));
                    }

                    pop();
                }
            }
        });

        slButton.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (sl == 1) {
                    sl = 0;
                    TextView ScrollLock = findViewById(R.id.sl);
                    ScrollLock.setText("0");
                    whacks++;
                    TextView NumberOfWhacks = findViewById(R.id.numberOfWhacksView);
                    NumberOfWhacks.setText(String.valueOf(whacks));
                    if (whacks > maxwhacks) {
                        maxwhacks = whacks;
                        TextView NumberOfMaxWhacks = findViewById(R.id.numberOfMaxWhacksView);
                        NumberOfMaxWhacks.setText(String.valueOf(maxwhacks));
                    }

                    pop();
                }
            }
        });

        // Capture our button from layout
        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        start.setOnClickListener(btnClickListener);
        cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(btnClickListener);
        time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);

        // Register the onClick listener with the implementation above

    }

    public float numAlea() {
        return r.nextFloat();
    }

    private void start () {

        time.setText("60");

        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(60 * 1000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                time.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish(){
                time.setText("Done !");
            }
        };
        countDownTimer.start();

        pop();

    }

    private void pop(){
        // Escolhe e "POPa" o botão

        // Gera número aleatório

        random0to1 = numAlea();

        if (random0to1 <= (1F / 3)) {

            cl = 1;
            Button clButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cl);
            clButton.setText("1");

        } else if (random0to1 <= 2F / 3) {
            nl = 1;
            Button nlButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nl);
            nlButton.setText("1");
        } else if (random0to1 <= 1F) {
            sl = 1;
            Button slButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sl);
            slButton.setText("1");
        }
    }

    private void cancel() {
        if (countDownTimer != null) {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            countDownTimer = null;
        }

        //Põe botões a zeros

        cl = 0;
        Button clButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cl);
        clButton.setText("0");

        nl = 0;
        Button nlButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nl);
        nlButton.setText("0");

        sl = 0;
        Button slButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sl);
        slButton.setText("0");

        whacks = 0;
        TextView NumberOfWhacks = findViewById(R.id.numberOfWhacksView);
        NumberOfWhacks.setText("0");

    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/whacksView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="WHACKS"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/maxWhacksView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="MAX WHACKS"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="24sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="60"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numberOfWhacksView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numberOfMaxWhacksView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="24sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Start" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Cancel" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just keep remaking the same CountDownTimer and have multiple instances of it running at once, that's what it'll do. You need to check to see if the timer is currently running before you start it again. There are two ways to do this.

## Method 1: Boolean

```
public CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
public boolean isTimerRunning = false;

private void start () {
    if (!isTimerRunning) {
        time.setText("60");

        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(60 * 1000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                time.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                isTimerRunning = false;
                time.setText("Done !");
            }
        };
        countDownTimer.start();
        isTimerRunning = true;

        pop();
    }
}
```

## Method 2: Null-Check

```
public CountDownTimer countDownTimer = null;

private void start () {
    if (countDownTimer == null) {
        time.setText("60");

        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(60 * 1000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                time.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                countDownTimer = null;
                time.setText("Done !");
            }
        };
        countDownTimer.start();

        pop();
    }
}
```